# Displaying custom name instead of class type in WPF propertygrid

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

Check out the following link in WPF PropertyGrid [documentation](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid#expandable_properties).
In the image of property grid, notice that the text displayed next to *Spouse* is

> Samples.Modules.PropertyGrid.Views.ExpandableProp

That doesn't look good when you are exposing a PropertyGrid to customers. How can I customize what I display there? Please note that TypeConverter doesn't work for WPF PropertyGrid. I have already tried that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the `ToString()` method of `Person` class and return whatever you want.

In the below code it returns the first name. With this change it displays the first name of the `Spouse` instead of `Samples.Modules.PropertyGrid.Views.ExpandableProp`

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return FirstName;
}
```